# visual studio dont recognize typescript packages

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-addin

I created a sharepointaddin app, and added 3 new ts item(app.component, app.module, main), and I implement these typescrit files as regular, but when I run, it throws these exceptions;
[image]
and here is the content of ts files;

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    message;
    constructor() {
        this.message = "Teddsdtddsad";
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent 
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and in the other hand all packages imported in ts files underlined and says this:
[image]

how can I fix this ? 
Note: there is all packages installed already;
[image]

Comment: How do you run your app? hitting F5? It might be that VS does not find the packages if they are not part of the solution. Try right-clicking, and then Add to solution (just a wild guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Typescript doesn't actually manage modules / packages. It just has language support for the ES2015 syntax. You have to add a module manager js file, like AMD and select it in the configuration file, or in the project -> properties -> Typescript Build

2) Try adding "./" in the the module path . Example: import { enableProdMode } from './@angular/core';

3) are you using external modules or just namespaces? Namespaces have a different syntax.